# Is it safe to stop mysql maintenance check in progress?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, maintenance

I am using HeidiSQL and running maintenance checks on all tables in the database (mysql 5.5.46-0+deb7u1-log) using:

```
CHECK TABLE `database`.`table` QUICK FAST MEDIUM
```

It just goes through and runs that command on each table, one at a time. However, I need to restart the server. Is it safe to kill this check without corrupting anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note what the [MySQL Documentation on `CHECK TABLE` says about running on InnoDB tables, bulletpoint 7 under the heading CHECK TABLE Usage Notes for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/check-table.html)

> When running CHECK TABLE on large InnoDB tables, other threads may be blocked during CHECK TABLE execution. To avoid timeouts, the semaphore wait threshold (600 seconds) is extended by 2 hours (7200 seconds) for CHECK TABLE operations. If InnoDB detects semaphore waits of 240 seconds or more it starts printing InnoDB monitor output to the error log. **If a lock request extends beyond the semaphore wait threshold, InnoDB aborts the process**. To avoid the possibility of a semaphore wait timeout entirely, you can run CHECK TABLE QUICK instead of CHECK TABLE.

`CHECK TABLE` never implies doing writes, just blocking other connections in the worst. `CHECK TABLE` should abort itself after 4 minutes as a courtesy to other connections. In your case, if there are other processes, wait 4-5 minutes. Then kill the process. If there is nothing else running, kill the process now. Doing a shutdown with it still running may block the shutdown for 4 minutes or more, but will eventually shutdown.

Please run `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0` beforehand.